# How to sort HTML elements alphabetically with vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

I have these animal cards in a container div, and i want to sort them alphabetically. I only want to use vanilla javascript, no jquery please.

```
  <div class="animal-container">
<div class="animal-cards">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="#">
  </div>
  <div class="animal-info">
    <div class="animal-name">Giraffe</div>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="animal-cards">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="#">
  </div>
  <div class="animal-info">
    <div class="animal-name">Camel</div>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="animal-cards">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="#">
  </div>
  <div class="animal-info">
    <div class="animal-name">Dog</div>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="animal-cards">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="#">
  </div>
  <div class="animal-info">
    <div class="animal-name">Lion</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please also show the javascript code that you tried! You can start with `getElementsByclassname()` or `querySelector()`

Comment: You may use an array to store the animals' data and sort the array and append the DOM from the array object.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with. I selected all tags with the class *"animal-name"*. Then stored their **textContent** in an Array, sorted it then replaced it in the original tags

```js
let animals = document.querySelectorAll('.animal-name');

let animalNames = [];
for(let i=0; i<animals.length; i++){
    animalNames.push(animals[i].textContent)
}

animalNames = animalNames.sort();

for(let i=0; i<animals.length; i++){
    animals[i].textContent = animalNames[i];
}
```

```html
<div class="animal-container">
<div class="animal-cards">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="#">
  </div>
  <div class="animal-info">
    <div class="animal-name">Giraffe</div>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="animal-cards">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="#">
  </div>
  <div class="animal-info">
    <div class="animal-name">Camel</div>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="animal-cards">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="#">
  </div>
  <div class="animal-info">
    <div class="animal-name">Dog</div>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="animal-cards">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="#">
  </div>
  <div class="animal-info">
    <div class="animal-name">Lion</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by appending the elements to the DOM dynamically using JS.

For example,

```
const arr = ["Giraffe", "Camel", "Dog", "Lion"].sort()
arr.forEach((word) => {
     document.getElementById("animal-container").appendChild(
    <div class="animal-cards">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="#">
  </div>
  <div class="animal-info">
    <div class="animal-name">{word}</div>
  </div>
    
)})
```

Comment: ```append``` should be ```appendChild``` instead

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to sort the DOM elements, and then append them in that order again inside the container element: this will actually *move* these elements in their right order:

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".animal-container");
const key = (a) => a.querySelector(".animal-name").textContent.trim();

Array.from(container.children)
     .sort((a, b) => key(a).localeCompare(key(b)))
     .forEach(child => container.appendChild(child));
```

```html
<div class="animal-container">
  <div class="animal-cards">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="#">
    </div>
    <div class="animal-info">
      <div class="animal-name">Giraffe</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="animal-cards">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="#">
    </div>
    <div class="animal-info">
      <div class="animal-name">Camel</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="animal-cards">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="#">
    </div>
    <div class="animal-info">
      <div class="animal-name">Dog</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="animal-cards">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="#">
    </div>
    <div class="animal-info">
      <div class="animal-name">Lion</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```